# mean(rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)) is not 0; and sd(rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1)) is not 1. Why?

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation

(Reproducible example added.)
I am little bit confused about rnorm function.
I expected `mean(rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1))` to be 0; and `sd(rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1))` to be 1. But gave different results. Where am I wrong?

**Reproducible Example:**

```
mean(rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1))
# [1] 0.07872548
sd(rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1))
# [1] 1.079348
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your sample size is to small, the larger the sample size, the closer the mean will get to 0 and the sd will get to 1.

Comment: `rnorm` gives you random variables which have a normal distribution with a 0 mean and 1 SD. "Random" means these values have been taken from distribution randomly, thus it is possible that a bigger proportion was taken from the right side opposed to the left side (for example). Still, your `mean` and a `sd` are very close. The bigger your data set will be, the closer they'll get by the LLN theory.

Comment: @JohnPaul, You should be right. But, interestingly, AFAIS, in "?rnorm" help documentation, there appears nothing as to the validity of this rnorm mean and sd only in the asympthotic case!

Comment: Also, try running `plot(sapply(1L:1e4, function(x) mean(rnorm(x))))` or `plot(sapply(1L:1e4, function(x) sd(rnorm(x))))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, Your technique is really very helpful not only for this problem but also for those who wonder long term behaviour in another problems. Thx.

Comment: very closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919091/r-generate-random-numbers-with-fixed-mean-and-sd

Comment: @BenBolker, I admired your miraculous solution at that link as well. I will make use of it that one as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`rnorm(100)` gives you a random sample of 100 values from distribution mean = 0 and sd = 1. Because it is random, the actual value of `mean(rnorm(100))` depends on which particular values you get back. There is no guarantee that the mean will be 0, but statistically it should converge to 0 as you use larger sample sizes. For example, try `mean(rnorm(10000))`; it will probably be closer to 0 than before.

Edit: If you want to force the sample to have a particular mean and standard deviation, check out this question: "[Generate random numbers with fixed mean and sd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919091/r-generate-random-numbers-with-fixed-mean-and-sd?lq=1)".

Comment: I thought rnorm(100,mean=0,sd=1) as "100 values whose mean is 0 and sd is 1", not as "100 values from a distribution with mean=0 and sd=1". Your explanation is very clear. I got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to noise. I would suggest to try with larger sets to approach the target, or change the seed to see various results.

Answer (score 0):

`rnorm` creates random deviates.

```
set.seed(4)
x <- rnorm(5, mean=0, sd=1)
x
# [1]  0.2167549 -0.5424926  0.8911446  0.5959806  1.6356180
mean(c(0.2167549, -0.5424926, 0.8911446, 0.5959806, 1.6356180))
# [1] 0.5594011
```

Comment: I get the mean of this as 0.5594011.

Comment: Thanks @JohnPaul forgot the `c` in `mean`

Comment: `mean(0.2167549, -0.5424926, 0.8911446, 0.5959806, 1.6356180) # 0.2167549`. I could not see the difference between `mean(c(...))` and `mean()`. Why are they not equal? Are we not taking the average of 5 numbers in both?