# Scale Dataset to Have Specific Mean and SD

Tags: r, statistics, mean

```
> set.seed(1)
> x = sample(1:100, 50, replace = T)
> summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00   33.25   43.50   49.88   73.75   97.00 
> sd(x)
[1] 26.05617
```

Let's say I have these data that show a mean of 49.88 and a SD of 26.056. Now, Let's say I wish to transform the vector x to have a mean 62 and SD of 19. How Can I transform these data to do so?

Comment: `alter_mean_sd <- function(x, new_mean, new_sd) scale(x)[, 1] * new_sd + new_mean` ?

Comment: there is another post about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919091/generate-random-numbers-with-fixed-mean-and-sd

Comment: How can I select your answers?